# Angular Error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Subscription'

Tags: angular

When I use the commented-out dataArray the data that I want was successfully retrieved.

However, error is prompted when I use the dataArray returned from `this.http.get()`.

How can I properly access the data array?

```
// var dataArray = [{ id: 15, name: "111" }, { id: 13, name: "abc" }];
var dataArray = this.http.get(apiURL).subscribe(response => response.text());

const userID = this.route.snapshot.paramMap('id');
var user = dataArray.find(x => x.id === userID);
this.userForm.patchValue(user);
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question rather than an image to your code

Answer (score 1):

`.subscribe` returns a *Subscription* and not the actual data you want to use. In order to use the data that is returned, you have to work within the callback to `.subscribe`. Please see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for a more in-depth explanation of code synchronization in JavaScript.

TypeScript errors are usually helpful. In this case it's telling you that type `Subscription` doesn't have a method `.find`. This is true ... and the reason is that `dataArray` is a `Subscription` (returned from the call to `.subscribe`) and not an array as you expect.

If you want to use the array returned from the response, you will have to access it inside of `.subscribe`:

```
this.http.get(this.apiURL).pipe(
  map(response => response.text()),
).subscribe(dataArray => {
  this.userForm.patchValue(dataArray.find(
    user => user.id === this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'),
  ));
});
```

---

Also, I don't think you should need to get every user for `patchValue`. Ideally you could do something like `` this.http.get(`/users/${userId}`) `` and skip the `.find`.